# How to add and remove components from particular coordinates in GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout, jform

I am new to swing, am trying to make a form in which you can navigate to different panels by the click of buttons on the left-hand side, to fill out forms(panels) appearing on the right-hand side, and I am using the GridBagLayout for the purpose. I am trying to remove the current panel on the click of the JButton and then add the corresponding panels I created by extending JPanel to classes. For ex., if I click on the accountDetailsButton, I wish to open up the accountDetails Panel, somewhat like switching tabs. I want to replace whichever panel is open on that position with the accountDetails Panel, and since any tab may be open, I need to exchange the panel on the basis of coordinates instead of the component name. I don't know how to go about it as I want to remove and add components on the basis of coordinates on the frame, and the name of the components may not be known. Here's the code.
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class FormWindow {
    private CustomerProfile customerProfile;
    private AccountDetails accountDetails;
    private LoanDetails loanDetails;
    private DocumentUpload documentUpload;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel logo;
    private JButton customerProfileButton;
    private JButton accountDetailsButton;
    private JButton loanDetailsButton;
    private JButton documentUploadButton;
    private JPanel bufferPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FormWindow");
        frame.setContentPane(new FormWindow().mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    FormWindow() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        bufferPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        customerProfile = new CustomerProfile();
        accountDetails = new AccountDetails();
        loanDetails = new LoanDetails();
        documentUpload = new DocumentUpload();
//        fieldForm.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc;
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        bufferPanel.add(customerProfile);
        mainPanel.add(bufferPanel, gbc);
        final GridBagConstraints gbcForms = gbc;

        logo = new JLabel();
        logo.setText("LOGO");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 10, 5);
        mainPanel.add(logo, gbc);

        customerProfileButton = new JButton();
        customerProfileButton.setText("Customer Profile");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        mainPanel.add(customerProfileButton, gbc);

        accountDetailsButton = new JButton();
        accountDetailsButton.setText("Account Details");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        mainPanel.add(accountDetailsButton, gbc);

        loanDetailsButton = new JButton();
        loanDetailsButton.setText("Loan Details");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        mainPanel.add(loanDetailsButton, gbc);

        documentUploadButton = new JButton();
        documentUploadButton.setText("Document Upload");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        mainPanel.add(documentUploadButton, gbc);

        //adding action listeners to buttons
        customerProfileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            }
        });

        accountDetailsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            }
        });

        loanDetailsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            }
        });

        documentUploadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I wish to display the corresponding panel on the right-hand side of the frame when the corresponding button is clicked. For ex., if I click the accountDetailsButton, I want to replace the previously visible panel with the accountDetails panel (the code for accountDetails has the accountDetails class extending JPanel). This is done to get the feel of switching between tabs in a way.

Comment: You should be using a `CardLayout` to swap panels. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for examples to get you started. *navigate to different panels by the click of buttons on the left-hand side* - so your main panel would use a BorderLayout. In the LINE_START you add your buttons panel. Then in the CENTER you add the panel to be used as the CardLayout to allow you to swap panels when you click a button.

Comment: See some runnable examples of using `CardLayout` : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54932151/3992939)   [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013230/3992939)   and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870789/3992939)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed